# How to simulate isActive value in false in a Koltin Coroutine test?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, jacoco

I would like to cover the throw line after the while loop in a suspend function like this

```
suspend fun doWork(): Result<Any> {
    while(isActive) { 
        /* ... do something */
        return something
    }
    throw Exception("...")
}
```

This is a generic idea of real code and I have tried two things to reach the solution:

1. Create a fake job but when I implemented Job interface I found some @InternalCoroutinesApi annotations so if not possible go by this way
2. Create an internal coroutine in the test function like this

```
@Test(expected = Exception::class)
fun `test when job is not active`() = coroutineDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
    launch(coroutineContext) {
        cancel()

        val sut = doWork()
    }
}
```

But this last one gives me a false positive and Jacoco it's not taking it. Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: What about simply: `withTimeout(100) { doWork() }`?

Comment: What is the actual idea of the real code? Why throw an exception after the loop? And why use `isActive` at all here? Do you call suspend functions in the loop?

Comment: the idea of real code is polling  data in an HTTP service until gets specific information and isActive is used here as a stop mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Point two in a way to create an inner coroutine and cancel it was ok to get isActive with a false value

```
@Test(expected = Exception::class)
fun `test when job is not active`() = coroutineDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
    launch(coroutineContext) {
        cancel()

        val sut = doWork()
    }
}
```

The **real clue for getting the solution** and right coverage was to set JaCoCo version to the last one in Gradle

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.8"
}
```

That's all. Thank you to everybody for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but there is a high chance you don't need `isActive` here at all.

You could just use `while(true)` and forget about the `throw` after the loop. If you have suspend function calls in the loop, they will likely detect cancellation on their own. If not, you can `yield()` to add some suspension points.

Note that `isActive` only works correctly if the current coroutine context has a `Job`, which might not always be the case (`suspend fun main` doesn't have a job, nor does `GlobalScope`). This is one of the reasons why I suggested deprecating `CoroutineContext.isActive` and [this issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/3300) was opened.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the issue link. Yes, I am using a SupervisorJob as a part of the coroutine context in a presenter.